# Why contract deployed return property contract.options.address null

Tags: web3js, ganache-cli

Why contract deployed return property contract.options.address null.

Inbox.test.sol

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const { send } = require('process');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = ganache.provider();
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
//var Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');

//let a = web3.transactionConfirmationBlocks;
//let b = web3.eth.transactionConfirmationBlocks;
//let c = web3.shh.transactionConfirmationBlocks; 

//console.log(a);
//console.log(b);
//console.log(c);

class Car {
    park() {
        return 'stopped';
    }
    drive() {
        return 'vroom';
    }
}
let accounts;
let inbox;
beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    var ad = accounts[0];
    inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface);
    inbox.deploy({data:'0x'+bytecode,arguments:['Hi there!']})
    .send({from:ad,gas:1000000});
    inbox.setProvider(provider);
});

describe('Inbox', () => {
    it('deploy a contract', () => {
        console.log(inbox.options.address);//null
    });
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^9.0.3",
    "solc": "^0.8.6",
    "web3": "^1.5.1"
  }
}
```

Inbox.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Inbox{
    string public message;
    
    constructor(string memory initialMessage) {
        message = initialMessage;
    }
    
    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public{
        message = newMessage;
    }
    /*function getMessage() public view returns(string memory){
        return message;
    }*/
}
```

compile.js

```
const path = require('path');
const fs   = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','Inbox.sol');
const source    = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'UTF-8');

//console.log(solc.compile(source,1));
//module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox'];
var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Inbox.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
};
//console.log(JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))));
//console.log(JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts);
//module.exports = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts['Inbox.sol'].Inbox.evm;
//console.log(module.exports);
//console.log(module.exports.contracts.sources);
//module.exports = solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input));
//console.log(JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))));
function findImports (path) {
    if (path === 'Inbox.sol')
        return { contents: source }
    else
        return { error: 'File not found' }
}
//console.log('abi',JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts['Inbox.sol']['Inbox'].abi);
//console.log('object',JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts['Inbox.sol']['Inbox'].evm.bytecode.object);
//const outpucleart = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input), findImports));
//console.log(output);
//console.log(JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts);
const val = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts['Inbox.sol']['Inbox'];
console.log('val',val);
module.exports.interface = val.abi;
//module.exports.interface = source;
module.exports.bytecode = val.evm.bytecode.object;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to deploy my contract, in Inbox.test.sol, miss it pass address to constructor like next

```
inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface,ad);
```